# $a < x < b \implies$ There is only one number $z$ such that $x = (1-z)a + (z)b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a < x < b$, then there is one and only one number $\lambda$ with $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $x = (1-\lambda)a + \lambda b$.

The book calls for proof of this statement.

Comment: I have already proved the existence, I only need help with the unambiguousness

Comment: Hint1. Can you show $x$ is a monotonic function of $\lambda$? Hint2: can you solve that expression for $\lambda$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Hint: you can write the equality also as $x=a+\lambda(b-a)$. Can you find an expression for $\lambda$?

Comment: But 3 < 4 for example. and 3 < (1-0.5)3 + (0.5)4 < 4 but also 3 < (1 - 0.6)3 + (0.6)4 < 4.

Comment: The question is that Lambda and not x is unique, there are infite x s wich satisfy this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by contradiction. Assume their is another such $λ_2$.
So, 
$(1-λ_1)*a+λ_1*b=(1-λ_2)*a+λ_2*b$
$(λ_2-λ_1)*a=(λ_2-λ_1)*b $
So, either $a= b$ or $λ_1=λ_2$. But, since there exists $x$ such that $a< x < b$, $a\neq b$. So,$λ_1=λ_2$.

Comment: "So, (1-λ1)*a+λ1*b=(1-λ2)*a+λ2*b. So, either a=b or λ1=λ2." That's quite a jump.

Comment: @Acccumulation fixed

Comment: Can you typset this in MathJax to improve its readability?

Answer (score 1):

The equation in $\lambda$ becomes $x-a=\lambda(b-a)$, that is,
$$
\lambda=\frac{x-a}{b-a}
$$
Therefore uniqueness is granted. Now prove that
$$
0<\frac{x-a}{b-a}<1
$$